# How do I summarise all columns except one(s) I specify?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to sum up all but one numerical column in this dataframe.

```
Group, Registered, Votes, Beans
A,     111,        12,     100
A,     111,        13,     200
A,     111,        14,     300
```

I want to group this by `Group`, summing up all the columns except `Registered`.

```
summarise_if(
  .tbl = group_by(
    .data = x,
    Precinct
  ),
  .predicate = is.numeric,
  .funs = sum
)
```

Problem here is the result is a data frame that sums ALL the numeric columns, including `Registered`. How do I sum all but `Registered`?

The output I want would look like this

```
Group, Registered, Votes, Beans
A,     111,        39,    600
```

Comment: Are the commas part of the values? It looks like you don't specify anywhere the column you want to leave out. Not clear how general you want this solution to be.

Comment: @AntoniosK Commas are not part of the data frame. I just thought they would make it easier to read

Comment: Some columns don't have commas though. Not a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit:

Modified versions of the two methods below for dplyr version >= 1, since `summarise_at` is superseded

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric) & !Registered, sum))

df %>% 
  summarise(across(-Registered, sum))
```

Original Answer:

I would use `summarise_at`, and just make a logical vector which is `FALSE` for  non-numeric columns and `Registered` and `TRUE` otherwise, i.e.

```
df %>% 
  summarise_at(which(sapply(df, is.numeric) & names(df) != 'Registered'), sum)
```

If you wanted to just summarise all but one column you could do

```
df %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-Registered), sum)
```

but in this case you have to check if it's numeric also.

Notes:

- factors are technically numeric, so if you want to exclude non-numeric columns *and* factors, replace `sapply(df, is.numeric)` with `sapply(df, function(x) is.numeric(x) & !is.factor(x))`

Comment: In the second solution, I get this error: "Evaluation error: ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors."

Comment: That means one of your numeric columns is a factor, so you'll have to convert it to a double or int before taking the sum, because sum is not meaningful for factors.

Comment: The `Group` column is the factor.

Comment: two options: replace `is.numeric` with `function(x) is.numeric(x) & !is.factor(x)` or, convert it to character

Comment: But if you put a `group_by(Group)` before `summarise_at`, you can leave it as-is

Answer (score 4):

We can use `summarise_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(-Registered) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
#  Votes Beans
#1    39   600
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt = read.table(text = "
Group Registered Votes Beans
A     111        12     100
A     111        13     200
A     111        14     300
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

# specify grouping variables
v1 = "Group"
v2 = "Registered"

dt %>%
  group_by_(v1, v2) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#     Group Registered Votes Beans
#     <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
#   1 A            111    39   600
```

Note that I have to assume that within each `Group` value there's a unique `Registered` value, so you can group by both variables, instead of grouping only by `Group` and keeping the unique value of `Registered`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, so by using the answer of @akrun [This answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522657/how-do-i-summarise-all-columns-except-ones-i-specify/53523977#53523977) I did

```
df <- as_tibble(df)

df %>%
select(-Type) %>%
summarise_all(sum)
```

Where "Type" is the non-numeric (char) column for example in the iris data set, Type is the "Species" columns. So I got the sum of all the other columns which happens to be numeric.